# WPF - Itemssource in a Button

Tags: wpf, button, itemssource

everyone,
I would like to add an Itemsource to a button so that I can access the sub-values. If I do the whole thing with ItemsControl, I get a button for each value. However, I only need one button. Can i limit this?

My Output: 30 Buttons -> I need 1.

My WPF Code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rechte}" >
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="Löschen"  Command="{Binding FoerderLoeschen}" FontSize="{Binding SelectedFont, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="{Binding Rechte.CanDelFPFoer, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" Padding="5 5 5 5" Margin="5 15 5 0"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: "*so that I can access the sub-values*" - what does that mean? Should all item commands be invoked by a click on the single Button?

Comment: @Sascha: Why are you using an `ItemsControl` if you only want to display a single `Button`?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the ItemsControl with a button so it becomes the button's content:

```
 <Button>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rechte}" >
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="Löschen"  Command="{Binding FoerderLoeschen}" FontSize="{Binding SelectedFont, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="{Binding Rechte.CanDelFPFoer, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" Padding="5 5 5 5" Margin="5 15 5 0"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
</Button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I still get several buttons instead of just one.

Comment: Of course it does not work. That's because there is an outer <Button> tag, which creates one button, as well as an inner <Button> tag, which creates N more buttons inside the first one.  Drop the inner one.

Comment: I need the binding of the inner button. Say, I need Rechte.CanDelFPFoer. I cannot access it outside of the ItemsControl.

Comment: @Sascha you asked how to "add an Itemsource to a button " the example  above does that if. if you have other questions, please submit these  separately